# RabbitMQ is dead

Tags: rabbitmq

I don't actually know how to describe my problem in my title well.  The issue I'm having is I have a local install of RabbitMQ through Homebrew (Mac), and it suddenly just died.  I suddenly became unable to send messages to the queue.  Unfortunately I can't post the error message, because I tried a few other steps, including resetting, uninstalling, and reinstalling Rabbit.  After the reinstall, I can't start my Rabbit server; it gets stuck after this:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server start
Password:
2022-08-05 11:14:17.972308-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979492-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] classic_mirrored_queue_version
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979531-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979546-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] maintenance_mode_status
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979568-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] quorum_queue
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979583-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] stream_queue
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979599-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] user_limits
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979611-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags:   [x] virtual_host_metadata
2022-08-05 11:14:17.979672-04:00 [info] <0.221.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2022-08-05 11:14:18.203961-04:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
2022-08-05 11:14:18.204012-04:00 [notice] <0.221.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output

  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.10.7
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2022 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Erlang:      25.0.3 [jit]
  TLS Library: OpenSSL - OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022

  Doc guides:  https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:     https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:   https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring:  https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log
        <stdout>

  Config file(s): (none)

  Starting broker... completed with 7 plugins.
```

After this it just hangs forever.

I would like to completely uninstall Rabbit from my computer and reinstall it from fresh; when I first installed it it worked like a charm, but since them somehow something has gone belly-up.  Can someone help me with this?

Also, yes, the obvious thing to do is `brew rm rabbitmq` but that's what got me into this situation.  It can't be that simple.

Comment: Long live RabbitMQ!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.  Some combination of these steps worked:

1. Change the permission of the service:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

2. Reload the launchctl config:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist          

launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
```

3. Restart the service:

```
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

And then it worked.